# How do I get Facebook chat to show me online friends on top instead of a random list on top and online friends at the bottom?

Tags: facebook

[image]

Now, its showing me some offline friends on the top and making me scroll to see the remaining friends who are actually online!!!

Comment: it's not exactly random; it's the friends that facebook 'thinks' you are most in contact with.

Answer (score 1):

There's no option built in Facebook UI till date, so NO, you can't sort your list.

Also, the Facebook API does not allows any such alteration.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change this currently in Facebook, nor can any sort of extension utilize  Facebook's API to do this. Also, the list generated is based on friends who you interact with the most (chat, commenting, etc...), therefore the more you interact with a person, the higher they should appear.

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view you can't add friends to this part, though it updates dynamically as the people you interact with change.
To find someone quickly, you can search for them by entering their name into the search field at the bottom of your sidebar.You can click on more friends to know rest of your friends who are in chat.